# Effect on pavement by light tracked vehicles with rubber inserts

Tags: mechanical-engineering, civil-engineering, highway-engineering

Is there data available to quantify the effect on pavement by light tracked vehicles with rubber inserts.  One example of such a vehicle is the [M113 armored personnel carriers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M113_armored_personnel_carrier) shown below.

[image: M113 armored personnel carrier]

Comment: Hi David, welcome to Stack Exchange. It could be helpful if you elaborated a bit on the project you're working on. How would you use the data? Can this be restricted to a specific region, pavement type, etc?